# How To Assign A Different Machine/Server As Build Agent In TeamCity?

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, teamcity-9.0

I'm just wondering on how to assign a different machine/server as a build agent in TeamCity.

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Can expand your question a bit as I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve - Did you want to install an additional build agent on another machine?

Comment: Hello @EvolveSoftwareLtd ! Appreciate your assistance! Anyway, i'm trying to install another build agent on my CI server, however I would want that build agent to be assigned to a different machine/server. Is it possible?

Comment: My current CI server's OS is windows 2003. The build agent machine that i want to assign is windows server 2008

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing a new build agent is a fairly straight forward process.

If you access your teamcity site (http://teamcity) through a browser from the target build agent machine (the windows 2008 server in this case) then you can download the installer directly to that machine.

1. Navigate to the administration section and click on Install Build Agents

[image]

2. Click on MS Windows Installer and download the agentinstaller.exe

[image]

3. Start the installer and ensure you are installing a windows service

[image]

4. Enter your destination directory for the build agent - This is where the working directory and configuration will reside, and click next to perform the installation
5. You then need to provide details of you TeamCity server so the agent can communicate back to the server. Enter the correct url of the server and choose a name for this agent and click save

[image]

7. Run the agent under the SYSTEM account for now, unless you have a dedicated network account (recommended) and start the build agent service

[image]

8. You will now need to enable the agent inside of the TeamCity UI (this may take a few minutes to appear). It will first appear as unauthorized and you'll have to wait for it to upgrade and reconnect.

[image]

Once this has happened, you can authorize the agent by clicking the Authorize agent button. A dialog will popup where you can enter some notes if required.

[image]

TeamCity Documentation - [Installing via MS Windows Installer](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Setting+up+and+Running+Additional+Build+Agents#SettingupandRunningAdditionalBuildAgents-InstallingviaMSWindowsinstaller)

There are limitations on the number of agents you can have under you license so you may need to purchase an additional one, but I suspect in this case you'll be okay - [TeamCity Licensing](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/buy/#license-type=new-license)

Hope this helps